# Android application crashes at activity change, possibly affected by layout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, textview

So this is something really strange that i cannot figure out.

I am developing a normal educational application on eclipse that is just supposed to have some exercises.

Everything was going pretty well, i had one of my exercises completed, then i decided to add a second exercise (at a new activity, like the first one)

So i added a new activity (Exercise3), with nothing in it, only the default textview that eclipse adds and i created an button that leads to that activity from my main menu.

The code is this, and is exactly the same code (different names off course) that works for my 1st exercise and perfectly changes forms.

```
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        // Capture button clicks
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainMenu.this,
                        Exercise3.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

There is absolutely no error in the log, and the app runs perfectly, but when i press button 2 to open the new activity i created, my application crashes.
Again, eclipse shows nothing, the code is exactly the same with my first button to activity which works perfect, but i don't know whats happening with this one.

There is only something strange though, on the new activity i add the standard "Hello World" textview that always is there is replaced by one saying "Error loading". In the mainmenu activity also where i had forgotten that standard textview, now it also says "Error loading" instead of "hello world".
(Just checked out this was done by my partner in this app from the strings.xml).

The xml is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.main.pirateisland.Exercise3" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I noticed that the id is missing from the textview, i tried adding it manualy, or completely erasing it and same problem, the application crashes when i try to go to that form from my button.

There is absolutely not error.warning whatsoever from eclipse which makes this quite confusing for me.

I guess there is something wrong with the xml, but i just cant find what. Maybe i changed something without noticing?

Also tried cleaning the project, restarting eclipse etc, nothing helps and the problem persists.

EDIT: Adding the manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.main.pirateisland"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.main.pirateisland.MainMenu" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_screen"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Exercise1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_exercise1"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplitActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_split"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Exercise3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_exercise3" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you add the new activity to the AndroidManifest.xml file ? Can you add your manifest file as well please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change context where activity will change.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, Exercise3.class);
```

Or

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Exercise3.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the action attribute `<action android:name="com.main.pirateisland.MainMenu" />` from the intent filter of `.MainMenu`

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And add the category DEFAULT intent filter to `.Exercise3`

```
<activity
      android:name=".Exercise3"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_exercise3" >
      <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```